# How to unit test "cache control" in http response - spring mvc application

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, caching, servlet-filters

I have the following filter to clear cache:

```
public class CacheControlFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        logger.info("doFilter method called clearing cache");

        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        resp.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
        resp.setHeader("Last-Modified", new Date().toString());
        resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        resp.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

I want to carry out a unit test to test if the `Cache-Control` is being set to `no-cache` when the above code is executed.

Basically I wanted to add some dummy value in the `Cache-Control` response header and execute my unit test to check if it is being set to `no-cache` for example.

I am using mockito and thats my starting point to carry out the test but i don't know how to set a dummy value `Cache-Control` to the response as shown below:

```
public class CacheControlFilterTest {

    @InjectMocks CacheControlFilter cacheControlFilter;
    @Mock ServletRequest request;
    @Mock HttpServletResponse response ;
    @Mock FilterChain filterChain;

    public CacheControlFilterTest() {}

    @Test
    public void doFilterTest() throws IOException, ServletException {
        cacheControlFilter.doFilter(request, response, filterChain);
    }
}
```

Any advice is most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should add the *Mockito Runner*, if you're using JUnit:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CacheControlFilterTest { ... }
```

> Basically I wanted to add some dummy value in the Cache-Control
>   response header and execute my unit test to check if it is being set
>   to no-cache for example.

In order to do that, i would personally prefer to use spring's mock implementations of `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse`, which are `MockHttpServletRequest` and `MockHttpServletResponse`, respectively. So, your `CacheControlFilterTest` would be something like following so far:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CacheControlFilterTest {
    @InjectMocks CacheControlFilter cacheControlFilter;
    @Spy MockHttpServletRequest request;
    @Spy MockHttpServletResponse response;
    @Mock FilterChain filterChain;

    // The rest will be roll out very soon!
}
```

Then you can user those mock implementations in your test, something like:

```
@Test
public void doFilterTest() throws IOException, ServletException {
    final String CACHE_CONTROL_VALUE = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "some value");

    cacheControlFilter.doFilter(request, response, filterChain);

    assertEquals(response.getHeader("Cache-Control"), CACHE_CONTROL_VALUE);
}
```